# How to install recoll dependencies "djvutxt" and "python3:pylzma"?

Tags: software-installation, python, djvu, recoll, lzma

I installed recoll on my Kubuntu 20.04. Now it says that external apps and commands are missing that are required for the indexing are missing, specifically:

```
djvutxt (image/vnd.djvu)
python3:pylzma (application/x-7z-compressed)
```

but I have no idea how to install them. No such packages are shown in muon (my package manager GUI). How can I install them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt install djvulibre-bin
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install pylzma
```

**edit**

Install [`backport.lzma`](https://pypi.org/project/backports.lzma/):

```
sudo apt install liblzma-dev
pip3 install backports.lzma
```

Comment: Thanks, djvu worked, but recoll still says that `python3:pylzma (application/x-7z-compressed)` is missing. Other python related helpers, were installed by me via `apt-get install python3-...`, where `...` would be the name of the related helper. However, there is no package `python3-pylzma`.

Comment: `liblzma-dev` is already installed and `pip3 install backport.lzma` returns "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement backport.lzma (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for backport.lzma"